# What is the difference between listen and forEach in Dart streams?

Tags: stream, dart

If I have `Stream` in Dart, I can use both `listen` and `forEach`, but I don't understand the difference.

So for example consider this code:

```
final process = await Process.start('pub', ['serve']);
process.stdout.map((l) => UTF8.decode(l)).forEach(print);
```

I could also have written:

```
process.stdout.map((l) => UTF8.decode(l)).listen(print);
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `forEach` function on a `Stream` will stop at the first error, and it won't give you a `StreamSubscription` to control how you listen on a stream. Using `forEach` is great if that's what you want - it tells you when it's done (the returned `Future`) and all you have to do is handle the events. If you need more control, you can use the `listen` call which is how `forEach` is implemented.

It's like the difference between `Iterable.forEach` and `Iterable.iterator` - the former just calls a callback for each element, the other gives you a way to control the iteration.

Comment: Is it correct to say the async syntax "`await for (var x in stream) {}`" is sugar for "`stream.forEach( (x) { ... } );`" ?

Comment: Basically, yes. It's not implemented exactly that way due to the extra requirement that `await for` pauses the subscription if the body is async, but for a simple loop with a synchronous body, it's equivalent to `await stream.forEach((x) { ...  });`. The leading `await` ensures that an error raised in the body or the stream is propagated correctly.